# How can I create a splunk query to show when there is activity from a country which has not shown activity in the prior 90 days?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm  generally new to using Splunk and I've been assigned a task to create a stats table that would show countries that have not been active for at least 90 days but are showing activity the day of the search. Looking for some guidance to point me in the right direction in terms of what commands/searches to use in order to build a query that would meet this requirement.

Comment: Are you allowed to have a look-up table of all possible countries?

Comment: I'm able to use iplocation and pipe a stats command to create a table of all countries and their ip counts. So if that answers your question, then yes.

Comment: If you can create a **static** table of **all** countries, then yes, it is possible to have a Splunk query that will show the sub-list with no activity in the last 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

Finding what's not there is not Splunk's strong suit so building a list of countries not heard from will be a challenge.  Try turning it around: build a list of countries active in the last 90 days then alert when there's activity from a country not on the list.

Build the list by running a daily report that searches over the last 90 days for "activity".  Look up the source countries, remove duplicates, then save only the country names to a lookup file.

```
index=foo <<search for activity>>
| iplocation ip
| fields Country
| stats count by Country
| fields - count
| outputlookup countries.csv
```

To find new countries, use the lookup file to rule out countries seen recently.

```
index=foo <<search for activity>>
| iplocation ip
| search NOT [ | inputlookup countries.csv | format ]
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helps